# OSX audio editor with batch silence crop?

Tags: batch-processing, silence, strip-silence

Hi guys,

i'm seeking for an audio editor which allow to remove silence from beginning and end of a set of audio files... something like auto trim/crop of soundforge.

I already use Logic Pro 9 'strip silence' feature to create new regions and convert them to new sound clips. Then I need to further process those clips to remove silence in beginning/end.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 4):

Sample Manager will do it.

Comment: +1 for Sample Manager. Very quick and clear workflow, especially when working with multiple files. 

Comment: +1 again for Sample Manager. Fast, stable, and easy to use. I've routinely pushed batches of 1k-5k files through it without trouble. And as a side note, they're voXover app is awesome.

Comment: Another +1 for Sample Manager. Powerful program with some great workflow strategies in place. Exceptional.

Answer (score 2):

Try Twisted Wave. Had batch processing and silence removal features.

Comment: +1 x 10,000! Just fell in love with this little gem of an app recently. Not only does it have excellent batching, it's got terrific metadata support (including Soundminer) and some great editing features. I just ditched the recently killed Soundtrack Pro after a good 7-8 years for Twisted Wave. Love it. 

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys and thanks for your replies. I've tried both, but can't find something quick as much as soundforge was. i'll keep seeking ;)

Thanks again,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

I believe Audition is the one that comes closest to the old-school soundfile editors.. Shame even that isn't on par.